Google Sheets Pivot for True (Imported data checkbox true/false)
I have a pivot that has other data and filters. I cannot filter out false. I am needing to show in the pivot checkbox that shows true only. Please help!
I've tried if formulas, counta, count, sum in the pivot
I am unable to solve this issue.

Please provide a sample sheet link with a before and after showing how you want it to look. Just simplify it with minimal fake data to simulate the problem.
